# Deploy Google Application Credentials to Meteor Cloud?

Tags: meteor, deployment, environment-variables, cloud, google-apps

I'm trying Meteor Cloud for the first time, and I've run into an issue using Google's Speech-to-text service on my deployed site. Locally I export a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable that points to a JSON file with connective info for Google. This works great, and I've defined that environment variable  in my settings.json file for meteor, but I don't know how to get the meteor deploy to submit the json file as part of the build process so it can be recognized, and I'm having issues finding any reference to the process.

Is there an easy way to do that that I'm missing? Google requires a JSON file, it seems, so I don't believe I can just paste the JSON data in as an environment variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a corresponding, anonymized, code example?

Comment: @brian-hogg how did you solve this issue ?